# how to generate bullet points from html to pdf using itext api when the bullets are at multiple locations in HTML

Tags: java, itext

While generating PDF from HTML on the fly, I am facing an issue. It’s like there are some bullet points in the HTML at multiple locations. the HTML is like this:

```
         <p>In regard to a "zero lot line" situation, extreme care should be 
  exercised in connection with:</p>

    <ul>
      `enter code here`<li> the right of legal access to and from the property. 
      <li>the possible existence of encroachments of the sides of the buildings or 
        structures upon the common areas.</li>
    </ul>

<p>In regard to a "zero lot line" situation, extreme care should be 
  exercised in connection with:</p>
  <ul>
  <li> the right of legal access to and from the property. 
  <li>the possible existence of encroachments of the sides of the buildings or 
    structures upon the common areas.</li>
</ul>
<p>In regard to a "zero lot line" situation, extreme care should be 
  exercised in connection with:</p>
  <ul>
  <li> the right of legal access to and from the property. 
  <li>the possible existence of encroachments of the sides of the buildings or 
    structures upon the common areas.</li>
</ul>
```

I parsed the HTML like this:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

                Elements links = doc.select("ul li");
                List list = new List(false, 20); 
                for (Element element : links) {
                     list.setListSymbol("\u2022"); 
                     list.add(element.text());  
                }

           document.add(list);
```

but by doing this, it trims everything after the bullets section. it prints only the first instance of the bullets.

Please help me doing this. Is there a way of storing multiple sections in a list and then finally converting the complete list to PDF?

Thanks in Advance !!